# Java benefit of using Parameter binding with NamedParameterJDBCTemplate

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

In Named Parameter JDBC Template, whats the value benefit of using parameter

```
parameters.addValue("noteId", noteIdVariable);
```

vs string replace in the actual query ?

```
modifiedPaymentQuery = sqlQuery.replace(":noteId",noteIdVariable);
```

Is it faster performance, less memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, formats like parameters have a lower performance than replace in the query directly.

***But*** Here is the thing, if we talk about the security perspective parameter es better, why is this?

Parameters have some basic rules to prevent sql injection in because if you have a string like this `"select * from table where noteId=':noteId'"` and some put as `:noteId` something like `"' or 1=1; -- -"`  you will be hack soon if you replace the string directly